# App crashes sometimes when starting videoview

Tags: android, crash, android-videoview, freeze

I am using VideoView to play live streams and it works fine most of the time, but sometimes the app freezes for a moment and either continues to play or crash and send me to home screen.
This is what happens when i select an item from the listview or click `KEY_DOWN / KEY_UP`:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        if (mVideoView != null && mListView == null) {
            if (listViewNext != listViewCurrent) { playChannel(listViewNext, 0); }
            return true;
        }
    }
}

private void playChannel(int channel, int id) {
    listViewCurrent = channel;
    listViewNext = listViewCurrent + 1;
    listViewPrev = listViewCurrent - 1;
    if (mListViewChannels == "Danish") {
        if (listViewNext >= arrayDanishChannels.size()) { listViewNext = 0; }
        if (listViewPrev < 0) { listViewPrev = arrayDanishChannels.size() - 1; }
        mListViewLink = arrayDanishLinks.get(listViewCurrent);
    } else if (mListViewChannels == "World") {
        if (listViewNext >= arrayWorldChannels.size()) { listViewNext = 0; }
        if (listViewPrev < 0) { listViewPrev = arrayWorldChannels.size() - 1; }
        mListViewLink = arrayWorldLinks.get(listViewCurrent);
    }

    String listViewName = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(listViewCurrent);

    String[] links = mListViewLink.split(";"); int temp = id + 1;
    if (id < 0 || temp > links.length) { id = 0; temp = 1; }
    mListViewLink = links[id]; listViewLinkId = temp; listViewLinkIds = links.length;

    startVideo(listViewName+" ("+listViewLinkId+"/"+listViewLinkIds+")", mListViewLink);

    mListViewCurrent = mListViewChannels;
}

private void startVideo(String title, String link) {
    toastDisplay.cancel();
    setInfoView(title);
    imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    videoView.removeCallbacks(videoRunnable);
    videoView.stopPlayback();
    MediaController media = new MediaController(MainActivity.this); media.setAnchorView(videoView); media.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(media);
    videoView.setVideoPath(link);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(videoViewPreparedListener);
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(videoViewErrorListener);
    videoView.setVisibility(VideoView.VISIBLE);
    videoView.postDelayed(videoRunnable, videoViewTimeOut);
    videoView.start();
    mVideoView = "true";

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("setLastStream", title+";"+mListViewChannels);
    edit.apply();
}
private void setInfoView(String title) {
    infoView.removeCallbacks(infoRunnable);
    infoView.setText(title);
    infoView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
}
```

Just a note: I have payed for the streams and some are free to access for anyone, no illegal content.
I am using an android set top box with firmware 4.4.2
I have tried to add `try { .. } finally { .. }` everywhere and it still freezes sometimes at random times.
Please help, im new in making apps and this is really driving me crazy.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you share the logged crash exception?

Comment: I would love to, but as I said im pretty new at this so i dont know where to get it. Can you point me at the right direction?

Comment: Depends a lot on your test system. If you're using an IDE look for the logcat out put. If you're using an actual device you can install a logcat reader

Comment: I am using an actual device, my set top box, and i have installed logcat reader but its not really giving me anything. Does it require root?

Comment: I have intregated the [Splunk MINT SDK](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintSDKs/latest/SplunkMINTSDKs/RequirementsandinstallationforAndroid) and its still not reporting any errors when it crashed randomly, but when i added `String a = null; a.toString();` it reported the NullPointerException error, So im guessing that it isnt any exception error? But what else could it be?

Comment: Could it possibly have anything to do you with that I am using videoView.start(); instead of using the MediaPlayer in onPreparedListener to start the video? EDIT: Nope, i removed the videoView.start(); and add mp.start(); in the onPrepared listener and it crashed again.

Comment: I had some trouble with video crashing weirdly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642401/how-to-force-alpha-blending-on-a-videoview . Unfortunately I really think you have to find a way to attach a debugger or at least get the logs, I don't know much about set top boxes